# Integral over all possible 2-dimensional lines (maybe variance related)

Tags: integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I'm working on some image software and was hoping for any feedback on an integral that came up:

$$M = \int_{\mathbb{L} \in \Omega} \int_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{L}} F'_L(x,y)^2$$

If there is a better way to write this an edit would be welcome.  What I am trying to express is:

- $F$ is a function $\mathbb{R} ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
- $\Omega$ is the set of all lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$
- $F_L$ is the function obtained by restricting the domain of $F$ to the line $L$: in a sense it is 1 dimension to 1 dimension even if the input is specified with 2 dimensions
- $F'_L$ is the derivative of $F$ along $L$, the sign doesn't matter since it is squared

So the integral should be calculating something like the total variance of the change in $F$ along all possible lines through it's domain.

I've been looking for a way to convert this integral into a single integral over the domain of $\mathbb{R^2}$, such as:
$$M = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{ something } dx\, dy$$

It looks very similar to variance, which has a lot of nice properties for sums, but I think that since the lines are all dependent then I'll have to look at covariance formulas as well.

I'll add edits as I figure out anything, but any pointers on manipulating this integral is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Integral can be written as
$$M = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{S^1} \int_0^\infty (\theta \cdot \nabla F(r\theta+te))^2\ dr\,d\theta\,dt$$
Where $\cdot$ denotes the inner product and $S^1 = \{(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)\,|\,\phi\in[0,2\pi)\}$, $e=(1,0)^T$